# "Blue box" showing up next to custom UIButton in iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uibutton

I'm developing an iPhone app that acts as a remote for switching lightbulbs on and off, and I'm using UIButtons to do this:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

[button setBackgroundImage:bulb_on forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[button setBackgroundImage:bulb_off forState:UIControlStateNormal];

button.frame = CGRectMake(SPACING_LEFT + (BUTTON_SPACING * buttonNum) % (NUMBER_OF_HORIZONTAL_BUTTONS * BUTTON_SPACING), SPACING_TOP + y_padding, BUTTON_SIZE_X, BUTTON_SIZE_Y);

[self.scrollView addSubview:button];
```

Everything works fine, except a little, but still annoying detail:

[image: buttons]

As you can see, there is some kind of blue "box" or shadow in the top left corner of the selected button. The button in normal state has no such thing. What can this come from, and how to remove it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think it s because you created a `UIButtonTypeRoundedRect` not a `buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom`

Do it like this:

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectMake(SPACING_LEFT + (BUTTON_SPACING * buttonNum) % (NUMBER_OF_HORIZONTAL_BUTTONS * BUTTON_SPACING), SPACING_TOP + y_padding, BUTTON_SIZE_X, BUTTON_SIZE_Y)];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

[button setBackgroundImage:bulb_on forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[button setBackgroundImage:bulb_off forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self.scrollView addSubview:button];
```

Comment: Works. It seems that if button is system type, it shows some kind of rounded rect in top right corner when selected. I just changed type in IB to Custom and it works ok. +1

Answer (score 7):

By default button type is `System`, Change type of your button to `Custom`.

---

**Code to fix:**

`[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];`

---

**Storyboard to fix:**

Refer screenshot to fix in stroryboard.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Try this in programmatically `[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];`